# How to exactly match string when there is variable in regex

Tags: python-3.6

I'm Trying to create phone book program using python3. If name/phone number given already exist in phone book i need to inform the user to give unique name/number. Below is my code

```
import re,os

take_input='yes'

def duplicate_exists(arg):
    if os.path.exists('ph_dir.txt'):
        with open('ph_dir.txt','r') as rp:
            contents=rp.read()
            res=re.findall(arg,contents)
            if res:
                print(f"{arg} already exist.")
                tk_ip='yes'
            else:
                tk_ip='no'
    return tk_ip

while take_input == 'yes':
    name=input("Enter the name:")
    phno=input("Enter phone number:")
    name=name.strip()
    phno=phno.strip()

    take_input=duplicate_exists(name)
    take_input=duplicate_exists(phno)


with open('ph_dir.txt','a') as wp:
    contents=wp.write(f'\n{name}:{phno}')
```

In the above code i'm using `duplicate_exists()` to find the duplicate for both `name` and `phno`

`ph_dir.txt` already has below entry

`abcd:12345`

now if i give the input as `abc` and `123` it says already exists.

**Improper op:**

```
Enter the name:abc
Enter phone number:123
abc already exist.
123 already exist.
Enter the name:
```

I tried word boundary `res=re.findall(\barg\b,contents)` in regex. But this will give syntax error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`. I'm using same function to find duplicate of phone number also. So i cant hard code any value here. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this regex: `re.findall(f'{arg}:.*|.*:{arg}', name)`

```
def duplicate_exists(arg):
    if os.path.exists('ph_dir.txt'):
        with open('ph_dir.txt','r') as rp:
            contents=rp.read()
            res=re.findall(f'{arg}:.*|.*:{arg}', contents)
            if res:
                print(f"{arg} already exist.")
                tk_ip='yes'
            else:
                tk_ip='no'
    return tk_ip
```

also you can check both `name` and `phno` in one regex matching:

```
def duplicate_exists(name, phno):
    if os.path.exists('ph_dir.txt'):
        with open('ph_dir.txt','r') as rp:
            contents=rp.read()
            res=re.findall(f'{name}:.*|.*:{phno}', contents)
            if res:
                print(f"{name} or {phno} already exist.")
                tk_ip='yes'
            else:
                tk_ip='no'
    return tk_ip
```